# Is there an If Statement substitute "If(x>constant,1,0)" that can be used in an Excel Solver linear programming model?

Tags: excel, vba, linear-programming, solver

[Excel Solver Model Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIM5W.png)

I have a shipping model where I would like to minimize the number of shipments we make, by choosing the optimal amount to ship each week, while keeping the company we send product to within a target Quantity on Hand range. One of the constraints is that a shipment cannot cause their Quantity on Hand to rise above a maximum demand constant for 3 straight weeks (In this example the Max is 30). To do this, I would like to add an if statement that accounts for this on each week such as:
{If x > 30 y = 1 Else y = 0}

However, excel solver does not allow for if statements in the model, and I am unsure if there is a method available to substitute the if statement with something usable in the model.

I have tried to express the if statement as a continuous variable, as such:
x > 30*y
y ∈ {0,1}
but I don't understand how to apply that so that it tells me if the Ending Balance is above the max for 3 weeks in a row. It works if I am only making sure that 1 week is not above the max, but I need to know for 3 weeks in a row.

Answer (score 0):

`If(x>constant,1,0)` would make the problem non-linear, so we can't use the simplex solver. (In Excel both the LP and MIP solver are called "Simplex Algorithm").

Instead of `{If x > 30 y = 1 Else y = 0}` it is usually enough to enforce:

```
   y=0 ==> x<=30
```

(because of the role of the objective in the model). This implication can be written as:

```
   x <= 30 + y*U
```

where `U` is an apriori upper-bound on `x`.